# jquery each function -> class name is "undefined" for $(".row > div").each(function(i) {};

Tags: jquery, variables, undefined, each

I receive a "myval: undefined" message for the following code.
I'm wondering how to get the class anme of the current class?

This is my function:

```
$(".row > div").each(function(i) {
            var myval = $(this).attr('class');
             console.log ("myval: " + myval)
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="item1">item</div>
 <div class="item2">item</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="item3">item</div>
 <div class="item4">item</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="item5">item</div>
 <div class="item6">item</div>
</div>

etc.
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Could you provide a fiddle that reproduces the `undefined` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in the right way and the result is as expected

```js
$(".row > div").each( function(i) { // Removed i as not in use
            var myval = $(this).attr('class');
             console.log ("myval: " + myval)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  
  <div class="row">
 <div class="item1">item 1</div>
 <div class="item2">item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="item3">item 3</div>
 <div class="item4">item 4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="item5">item 5</div>
 <div class="item6">item 6</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, sorry there was a mistake in my initial code. thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any issue with your code, check you have included the jQuery library correctly.

Example here:
http://jsbin.com/rutameg/edit?html,js,console,output

```js
$(".row > div").each( function() { // Removed i as not in use
            var myval = $(this).attr('class');
             console.log ("myval: " + myval)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  
  <div class="row">
 <div class="item1">item 1</div>
 <div class="item2">item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="item3">item 3</div>
 <div class="item4">item 4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="item5">item 5</div>
 <div class="item6">item 6</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, sorry there a mistake in my initial code, thanks for your efforts!